# BeautiFulSoup4 не могу вытащить номер

Tags: python, beautiful-soup

На сайте появляется номер после клика.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


product = input()
headers = {
   "Accept": "*/*",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.66 Safari/537.36 OPR/89.0.4447.38"
}
url = "https://lalafo.kg/kyrgyzstan/q-" + product

request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
bs = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')

all_links = bs.find_all()

for link in all_links:
    print(link)
```

после вот такого кода в парсер появляется номер под mobile как его вытащить?
[image: после кода]

Comment: Буду признателен если поможете.

Comment: Посмотрел как на сайте и понял, что инфа хранится в json. Нашел какой-то кусок json в `script` c `id=__NEXT_DATA__`, вы можете вытащить его так `data_str = bs.select_one('#__NEXT_DATA__').text`, далее используя модуль `json` распарсить `data = json.loads(data_str)`. Далее мне уже не лениво было разбираться :)

Comment: посмотри что какой тип данных тебе приходит в ответе если словарь обратись по ключу,
мне кажется что ты не правильно получаешь данные с сайта, но слишком мало информации

Comment: @Dick Dikins так по мне информаций предоставлено предостаточно, даже код до определенного момента рабочий :)

Comment: Так а что вводить то, `input` требует ввода. Что вводить, как вашу ситуацию промоделировать?

Comment: @CrazyElf да что угодно, что ваша душа пожелает найти на lalafo.kg :)

Answer (score 2):

Нужная вам информация лежит в тегах `script`. Так что ищем скрипты, грузим их как `json` и проходим рекурсивно по получившимся структурам в поисках нужных ключей, а также выкидываем пустые найденные элементы:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json

def item_generator(json_input, lookup_key):
    if isinstance(json_input, dict):
        for k, v in json_input.items():
            if k == lookup_key:
                yield v
            else:
                yield from item_generator(v, lookup_key)
    elif isinstance(json_input, list):
        for item in json_input:
            yield from item_generator(item, lookup_key)

product = input()
headers = {
   "Accept": "*/*",
   "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.5060.66 Safari/537.36 OPR/89.0.4447.38"
}
url = "https://lalafo.kg/kyrgyzstan/q-" + product

request = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
bs = BeautifulSoup(request.text, 'lxml')

all_links = bs.find_all('script', type='application/json')
for script in all_links:
    data = json.loads(script.text)
    for item in item_generator(data, 'mobile'):
        if item:
            print(item)
```

При вводе `notebook` получаем такой вывод:

```
+996559644044
+996558014210
+996558014210
+996700352772
+996505776771
+996558014210
+996703797552
+996507144931
+996555049725
+996770301501
+996502018180
+996773977449
+996755501907
+996550663391
+996700105070
+996509664422
+996700777720
+996990222020
+996558983798
+996703873395
+996550515971
+996704524777
+996700352772
+996558656545
+996550849217
+996702082288
+996500127776
+996772950064
+996556973999
+996707080807
+996505845651
+996706474008
+996555499939
+996554020032
+996505845651
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import requests

product = "сотовый телефон"
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:102.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/102.0',
    'device': 'pc',
}

params = {
    'expand': 'url',
    'per-page': '400',
    'q': product,
    'page': 1,
}


response = requests.get('https://lalafo.kg/api/search/v3/ads/search', params=params, headers=headers)
jsn = response.json()
for z in jsn['items']:
    print(z['title'])
    print(f"{z['price']} {z['currency']}" if z['price'] else "Договорная")
    print(z['mobile'] if z['mobile'] else "Не указан")
print("Следующая страница")
print(f"https://lalafo.kg/api/search{jsn['_links']['next']['href']}")

Продам 4 старых сотовых телефона. торг
Договорная
+996559663882
Сотовый телефон "раритетный" рабочий. От,KATEL,, кто помнит
300 KGS
+996999681105
...
IPhone 7 Plus | 32 GB | Rose Gold Used
10000 KGS
+996500650302
Следующая страница
https://lalafo.kg/api/search/v3/ads/search?expand=url&per-page=50&q=%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9+%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%BD&page=2
```

Comment: Хорошо бы ещё пояснение писать - в чём суть кода. Обращаться по `api` - это отлично, но надо же и написать это всё в сопроводительном тексте.